# Room DB migration issue

Tags: java, android, sql, android-room

I am facing a problem related to migration. last week i joined a company and where i start working on a already exist project and build it with all correct migration and apply a force update to user but now some user are facing problem related of migration(Those who have very old version of app).
So there may possibility that last person didn't handle migration off Room DB now i don't know theme changes and crashlactic  also giving me HAlf info also don't know which version have problem so i want if there is some migration issue came then it should clear all db somthing like this

````
 Room.databaseBuilder(application, RoomDBHelper.class, DB_NAME)
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2, MIGRATION_2_3)
                .build();    }
catch(ex)
{
 Room.databaseBuilder(application, RoomDBHelper.class, DB_NAME)
.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded() .build();   
}```
````

Comment: Are you able to check version of app where the issue occurred ? Then you probably could check version of Room. How many migrations are there? It's very bad practice to clean user's db.

Comment: Crash is occurring in latest release But don't know previous app version . There are ~50  migrations.I know it's very bad practice but but I am not finding any solution.